# Struct, Queue, List with x,y, time values in C#? Compute average velocity from them

Tags: c#, data-structures

I originally have a struct to store x,y, and time coordinates in C# like

```
  struct handCoordinate {
         internal double x; 
         internal double y; 
         internal double time; 
  }
```

And was planning on using a queue to store this data. I need to compute the average velocities of that data and compare the next item to the previous. Would it make sense to use a queue to compare each handCoordinate item to each other and then use a list? Here's an example:

```
 handCoordinate(4.0, 0.01, 1.3)
 handCoordinate(-3.0, 0.02, 1.8)
```

In other words, what data structure would be the best to access these elements? Thanks!
(I can clarify more if needed)

Comment: The `struct` as you show it above is considered a "mutable" struct by many. You should be careful when writing to the fields since a struct is copied a passed by value. For example if `list` were a `List<handCoordinate>`, then e.g. `list[idx].x = 1.0;` would be disallowed (the indexer returns a _copy_ of the struct in the `list`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) makes more sense than a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) since you'll be iterating over it to compute the averages.  With a queue you can only guarantee that the items are popped in the same order in which they were pushed.  A sorted list, using the time as the key, will keep the items in time order regardless of which order they were inserted.  A sorted list also does not require that you remove the items in order to use them, making it easier to reuse the items if needed for other calculations without an additional data structure.

```
public struct HandCoordinate
{
     public HandCoordinate(double x, double y, double time)
     {
         this.X = x;
         this.Y = y;
         this.Time= time;
     }

     public readonly double X;
     public readonly double Y;
     public readonly double Time;
}

...

private static double Velocity(HandCoordinate p1, HandCoordinate p2)
{
     var time = p2.Time - p1.Time;
     if (time <= 0)
     {
         throw new ArgumentException("Duplicate measurement");
     }

     var dx = p2.X - p1.X;
     var dy = p2.Y - p1.Y;
     var distance = Math.Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

     // note the possibility for overflow if your times are very close together.
     // You might need to use logarithms for the calculation.
     return distance/time; 
}

...

var points = new SortedList<double,HandCoordinate>();
points.Add(1.0, new HandCoordinate(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));
points.Add(1.1, new HandCoordinate(1.0, 2.0, 1.1));
..

var velocities = points.Values
                       .Skip(1)
                       // note: because of the skip i in the following is the offset
                       // from the second element and can be used directly to refer
                       // to the previous element
                       .Select((p,i) => Velocity(points.Values[i],p))
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: `SortedList<,>`, then what should be `TKey` and `TValue`?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen `SortedList<double,handCoordinate>` using the `time` value as the key for each coordinate.

Comment: Awesome, that sounds great, thanks! So just to make sure, I still should use a sorted list with that struct? And what should I put the average velocities in? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Wow, you're the best, tvanfosson! Thank you! :)

Comment: Sorry if this is stupid, but how would I more precisely calculate the velocity with logarithms? Any links? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @m00nbeam360 - if time is very close to but not zero, it is possible to get an overflow error.  In that case you can use logarithms to possibly mitigate this by turning the division into exponentiation and the subtraction of the log values `return Math.Exp(Math.Log(distance) - Math.Log(time))`.  It's not really a question of accuracy, but rather avoiding overflow.

Comment: Perfect, that makes a lot more sense, thank you so much, tvanfosson!!